# what are the possible values of dim(Null(L))?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

can you please explain this question to me? Thanks

Question : Suppose that L: R^4 ----> R^2 is a linear transformation.

a) what are the possible values of dim(Null(L))?

b) For each possible value of dim (Null (L)) provide an example linear transformation L: R^4 ----> R^2 so that dim (Null (L)) is equal to that value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the dimension theorem which tells you that for $ L : V \rightarrow W$, we have:
$dim(V) = dim(null(L)) + dim(image(L))$.
Where all the numbers are natural numbers.
Hence you have $4 = dim(null(L)) + dim(image(L))$, however the image can be at most of dimension $2$,as it is a subspace of the codomain of L, hence we have that the dimension of the nullspace can be only 4,3,2

Comment: thanks, can you please explain part b. i  really appreciate your help

Comment: you just need to plug in the value of the nullspace into the formula. At this point you get the dimension of the image and you need to work made up a function with those properties, the easiest example I think would be with $dim(null(L)) = 4$, so $dim(image(L)) = 0$ and you have a map that maps everything to one element i think.